# Javascript Array of objects is returning a shorter length than it should

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an HTML page with 7 buttons. Using a "get" function returns the length of 4. It should be 7. Using inspect element, gives one detail in what I'm saying. I need the copyAllButtons array to be able to sort through the entire list, not just the 4 buttons.

[image: screenshot]

[image]

```js
let all_buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
console.log(all_buttons);

//Array of classes
let copyAllButtons = [];

//only loops through first  4 objects of object array. Why?
for (let i = 0; i < all_buttons.length; i++) {
  //console.log([i]);
  copyAllButtons.push(all_buttons[i].classList[1]);
}

console.log(copyAllButtons);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" >Click Me</button>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" >Reset</button>

<button class='btn btn-success' > Generate Random img </button>
<button class='btn btn-danger '> Remove img </button>

<button class="btn btn-primary">Wee!</button>
<button class="btn btn-danger">Yahoo!</button>
<button class="btn btn-warning">Google!</button>
<button class="btn btn-success">Facebook!</button>
```

Comment: Can you please update your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), preferably via [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: You should ```console.log(all_buttons.length)```. I think the result is 4. Then, you should investigate why can't you select all tags instead.

Comment: Are any of the EIGHT buttons dynamically created by code - looks like the first four have onclick handlers, and the last 4 don't - by the way `getElementsByTagName` returns a live HTML collection, so, if  you add some buttons they'll show up in there

Comment: The browser may auto-update the logged element array to show the most recent information, instead of what it was at the moment it was logged.

Comment: @Reyno I created the code snippet.

Comment: @Bravo No, none of the buttons are dynamically created.

Comment: the code snippet doesn't demonstrate the issue - also, it's odd that the first 4 (the number you're getting) are different from the last 4 - i.e. onclick handler vs no onclick handler - so the buttons are different in some way

Comment: by the way, if you run your script between `Remove img` image button and `Wee!` button, you get exactly the result you show

Comment: Running the snippet gives `"length": 8`, it's working as intended

Comment: I apologize if the code snippet is not working correctly, this is the first code snippet I have ever done, I tried editing it to make it better, but I kept getting errors.

Comment: That's the problem : she snippet _is_ working properly when it shouldn't :) It's not demonstrating your issue (the code works fine)

Comment: @JeremyThille This is odd. In Chrome, it shows that the object is of length 8, but in firefox of length 4. But still in Chrome, the loop only goes through the first 4 elements. Is all_buttons.length somehow the wrong property to call?

Comment: Well, your example code is working fine on both chrome and mozilla.

Comment: are these button hardcoded or being created dynamically?